# Can i programmatically start a WSGI application server without blocking the main thread of execution?

Tags: python, testing, wsgi

I'm writing a web application in python, and using [lettuce](http://packages.python.org/lettuce/tutorial/simple.html) with [splinter](http://splinter.readthedocs.org/en/0.0.3/) to write acceptance tests for it.

In order to do this, I need to get a wsgi server to start my application in the background, so that the  application is available for my test suite. To do this, I've been spinning up a waitress server instance in another thread, for the browser being driven to connect to:

```
def setUp():
    base = os.path.dirname(__file__) + "/../../.."
    world.app = loadapp('config:test.ini', relative_to=base)
    world.server_thread = thread.start_new_thread(serve_app,  (world.app,))

def serve_app(app):
    serve(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=7654)
```

This works quite nicely - The running application instance is available to my test suite in order to set up fixtures / mocks etc, and the server is available for my tests to connect to. However, when the tests finish, I've no way of sending a signal to the server to shut itself down cleanly. Therefore, is there anyway I can somehow either send a `KeyboardInterrupt` to the server thread I spawn (which will be caught by waitress and will prompt it to shut down cleanly), or failing that, is there an existing wsgi server implementation which exposes non-blocking `start()` and `stop()` methods that I could employ instead of waitress?

Comment: you probably shouldn't use `thread` directly (it is renamed to  `_thread` in Python 3). You could use `threading` module instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark the thread you run the WSGI server in as a daemon thread. That way when you exit the main thread it will not wait for the thread the server is running in to complete and will just exit the application.

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need WSGI server to unit-test a WSGI app, [example](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/testing/).

For you acceptance tests you could start the server in a separate process and send SIGINT when you're done.

If you'd like to stick with your current setup; you could run the server in the main thread and your tests in background threads. Then you could [send KeyboardInterrupt to the main thread from subthreads](http://docs.python.org/library/thread.html#thread.interrupt_main).

Comment: Aha! both good suggestions - I'd tried forking a process for the server before, but I'm trying to share the application instance between the threads (in order to set up fixtures, mocks etc and make assertions about its state), and since `fork()` has copy-on-write semantics, this isn't possible. Your second suggestion could work though, if I can somehow take the responsibility for spawning the server out of lettuce's setUp block, and have some other process spawn a subthread for the lettuce tests and then initialize the server. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is the problem just that the process won't shut down?

It's been a while since I've used Python for web development, so I've no experience of these libraries, but if shutting down is the problem it looks like a good scenario to use daemon threads.

Mentioned here:
http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html