# How to start an event-driven WSGI server without blocking my code

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, wsgi, python-multithreading

Started from this snippet from [python-socketio](https://python-socketio.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

```
import socketio
import eventlet
from flask import Flask, render_template

sio = socketio.Server()
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    """Serve the client-side application."""
    return render_template('index.html')

@sio.on('connect')
def connect(sid, environ):
    print('connect ', sid)

@sio.on('my message')
def message(sid, data):
    print('message ', data)

@sio.on('disconnect')
def disconnect(sid):
    print('disconnect ', sid)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # wrap Flask application with socketio's middleware
    app = socketio.Middleware(sio, app)

    # deploy as an eventlet WSGI server
    eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('', 8000)), app)     <====
```

The last line of code is blocking my code there, but I'd like to run it as a daemon and continue with more logic. Is that even possible.

I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11940492/can-i-programmatically-start-a-wsgi-application-server-without-blocking-the-main) and tried using `threading` as suggested, but I am afraid, that I am not doing it right.

```
wst = threading.Thread(target=eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('', 7000)), app))
wst.daemon = True
wst.start()
```

Any pointers?

## UPDATE

I tried this

```
    # wrap Flask application with socketio's middleware
    app = socketio.Middleware(sio, app)

    # deploy as an eventlet WSGI server
    # eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('', 7000)), app)

    wst = threading.Thread(target=self.serve_app, args=(app))
    wst.daemon = True
    wst.start()

def serve_app(app):
    eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('', 7000)), app)
```

but

```
@4000000056a6bbe61979723c Exception in thread Thread-1:
@4000000056a6bbe619797df4 Traceback (most recent call last):
@4000000056a6bbe6197981dc   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
@4000000056a6bbe6197985c4     self.run()
@4000000056a6bbe6197989ac   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
@4000000056a6bbe619798d94     self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
@4000000056a6bbe61979917c TypeError: serve_app() argument after * must be a sequence, not Middleware
@4000000056a6bbe6197a164c
```

what's the right way to do this?

## UPDATE 2

Changed a little the code

```
    wst = threading.Thread(target=self.serve_app, args=(sio))
    wst.daemon = True
    wst.start()
```

def serve_app(sio):
    app = socketio.Middleware(sio, app)
    eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('', 7000)), app)

as suggested passed a tuple `(app,)` but now getting this error

```
@4000000056a7543717fb2324   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
@4000000056a7543717fb270c     self.run()
@4000000056a7543717fb270c   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
@4000000056a7543717fb2af4     self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
@4000000056a7543717fb2edc TypeError: serve_app() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

this look like my missing out of Python syntax

## UPDATE 3 - RESOLVED

I had forgotten the `(self,`

```
       wst = threading.Thread(target=self.serve_app, args=(sio,app))
        wst.daemon = True
        wst.start()

def serve_app(self, _sio, _app):
    app = socketio.Middleware(_sio, _app)
    eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('', 7000)), app)
```

Comment: `(app)` doesn't create a tuple.. try `(app,)` or `[app]` on the `threading.Thread(...)` call

Comment: yes it looks like it was my problem thanks mate